# LinkedIn Link Sharing: Open Graph Image Issue

Tags: wordpress, facebook, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

NOTE: I've seen a variety of similar questions to this one so I'm going to try and be succinct in describing the issue along with what I've done so far.

The issue is that LinkedIn is failing to properly scrape images from articles on a WordPress site. The site is using All-in-One SEO to add the appropriate meta tags and these tags and, judging by facebook's sharing and object debuggers, is doing so correctly.

[Here's a sample article that demonstrates the issue.](https://dev-agilealliance.pantheonsite.io/linkedin-test/)

Upon entering the URI into a LinkedIn article, LinkedIn attempts to fetch the page's data. It returns with the title and description but leaves an empty space where the image would presumably display:

[image: Link preview displayed upon entering URL on LinkedIn]

In tailing the access logs, I've seen LinkedIn hitting the site along with 200 status codes for the page itself and the image:

```
[ip redacted] - - [29/Mar/2017:19:50:44 +0000]  "GET /linkedin-test/?refTest=LI17 HTTP/1.1" 200 23758 "-" "LinkedInBot/1.0 (compatible; Mozilla/5.0; Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1 +http://www.linkedin.com)" 0.906 "[ips redacted]"
[ip redacted] - - [29/Mar/2017:19:50:44 +0000]  "GET /wp-content/uploads/2017/03/modern-architecture-skyscrapers-modest-with-images-of-modern-architecture-ideas-on-gallery.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 510088 "-" "LinkedInBot/1.0 (compatible; Mozilla/5.0; Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1 +http://www.linkedin.com)" 0.000 "[ips redacted]"
```

Following some other Stack Overflow threads, I experimented with the following:

- Attempt to bust LinkedIn's cache with query strings

  - *Result: No change with query strings or completely new URLs*
- Verify image dimensions for `og:image` resource are not too small

  - *Result: No change was seen here in using images that match or exceed those indicated in [LinkedIn's knowledge base](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)*
- Revise all meta tags to include `prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#"`

  - *Result: No change*

I feel like I've hit a wall so any suggestions or thoughts are definitely welcome!

Thanks!

Comment: When you tried to add URL parameters for cache busting, did you modify the `og:url` as well …?

Comment: I actually haven't been doing that. That's a good point too as it's the value of `og:url` that actually gets scraped, huh? Cool-- I'll have to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work fine for me:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev-agilealliance.pantheonsite.io%2F
```

Source: [**Official Microsoft Documentation for Sharing on LinkedIn**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin/consumer/context).  Results:

[image]

*So, what changed???*  I did some digging.

Let's look at [the 2018 robots.txt file for dev-agilealliance.pantheonsite.io](https://web.archive.org/web/20180601161210/https://dev-agilealliance.pantheonsite.io/robots.txt), and compare it to [the working, 2020 robots.txt file](https://dev-agilealliance.pantheonsite.io/robots.txt).  Seems pretty clear.  This is why things were blocked in 2018...

```
# Pantheon's documentation on robots.txt: http://pantheon.io/docs/articles/sites/code/bots-and-indexing/
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

And this is the working robots.txt in 2020...

```
User-agent: RavenCrawler
User-agent: rogerbot
User-agent: dotbot
User-agent: SemrushBot
User-agent: SemrushBot-SA
User-agent: PowerMapper
User-agent: Swiftbot
Allow: /
```

Of course, it could also be that sharing services are much more lenient in 2020 than in 2017!  But things do seem to be working now, according to the above specs., I can confirm.